# Opscenter disks stats is not available when use NFS

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

In Opscenter 5.0.1 "Disk Capacity" and "Disks stats" is not available.

Cassandra data and commit log are in NFS mount points: /net/cassandra_data and /net/cassandra_log respectively.

I found the follow error in opscenterd.log:

```
2014-12-09 14:27:19-0200 [] Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/morbid/morbid.py", line 48, in dataReceived
    getattr(self, 'read_%s' % self.state)(**msg)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/morbid/morbid.py", line 102, in read_connected
    d.addCallback(getattr(self, 'frame_%s' % cmd))
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 297, in addCallback
    callbackKeywords=kw)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 286, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-debian/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 542, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/morbid/morbid.py", line 122, in frame_send
    self.factory.mqm.send_message(self, headers['destination'], (headers, body))
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/morbid/messagequeue.py", line 146, in send_message
    self.message_queues[dest_name].send(message)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/morbid/messagequeue.py", line 76, in send
    proto.send(self.prep_message(message))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/OrbitedService.py", line 265, in send

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Agents.py", line 294, in routeIncoming

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Agents.py", line 689, in processStorageInfo

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Cluster.py", line 1107, in updateStorageInfo

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/opscenterd/Cluster.py", line 1096, in sumDiskSpace

exceptions.KeyError: u'netapp_nfs:/vol/nfs_metadata_application_3_1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in OpsCenter. I created a ticket to fix it (internal ticket number is OPSC-4080). Hopefully it’d get fixed in the next patch release (5.1.x).

Sorry about that!

BTW I’m sure you’ve seen this page before, but if not: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/planning/architecturePlanningAntiPatterns_c.html?scroll=archPlanAntiPattern__shared-systems states that using NFS (or NAS) is an anti-pattern for C*.

Comment: Update: this is fixed in OpsCenter 5.2